# I am having trouble adding a delay to a jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a mega menu script I got from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml). It works perfectly except seeing as how I have a few of these on my page I would like there to be a delay that the user has to hold their mouse over the link before the menu opens.

I know I need to do this with a setTimeout() tag and a clearTimeout() for when the user does takes their mouse off the link. I just can not figure out where to put this. I've tried just guessing at it but no matter where I put this it seems to either break the function or not matter.

Thank you for any help anyone might be able to provide me with, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried? It would make it much easier to help.

Comment: yes! post what you have tried...

Comment: See this: `megamenu.$anchorobj.bind...` in their script? It binds the show code to the mousenter event, and similarly it hides on mouseleve. The latter already has a delay timer - use the same strategy.

Comment: @sej397 I tried adding it in like this `megamenu.$anchorobj.bind(megamenu.revealtype=="click"? "click" : "mouseenter", function(e){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        var menuinfo=jkmegamenu.megamenus[parseInt(this.getAttribute("_megamenupos"))]}
                        , 2000)
   clearTimeout(menuinfo.hidetimer) //cancel hide menu timer
   return jkmegamenu.showmenu(e, parseInt(this.getAttribute("_megamenupos")))
           
  })` and the script didn't work then

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is something like this?

```
var timeout;
$('#menuID').mouseenter(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $(this).children().show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).children().hide();
  },400);
});
```

Note that the maker used the same way as above:

"*p.s: Inside the .js file, there are two variables you may wish to fine tune:*"

```
effectduration: 300, //duration of animation, in milliseconds
delaytimer: 200, //delay after mouseout before menu should be hidden, in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to add a delay on whatever you want

```
// Function declatation
var delay = (function()
{
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms)
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

usage:

```
delay(function()
{ 
    // Do thing you want delayed
}, 1000 );
```

Replace `1000` with amount of ms you want to delay

---

**EDIT**

```
$("#menuitem").mouseenter(function()
{ 
    delay(function() 
    { 
        if($(this).is(':hover')) 
            // Show menu
    }, 1000 );     
});
```

Comment: I quite like your delay () implementation, but I don't think it'll help the OP because they still have the same problem as with setTimeout() in that they don't know where to add it to their existing code. Also I think they'll need to be able to cancel the queued function when the user moves the mouse out...

Comment: Use it as the `mouseover` function and when the delay ends, check if the mouse is still hovering on it `$("#menuitem").mouseenter(function(){ delay(function()
{ 
    if($(this).is(':hover'))
  // Do thing you want delayed
}, 1000 ); });`

Doesn't look as good as comment, I'll make an edit

Comment: OK I added it like this: `megamenu.$anchorobj.bind(megamenu.revealtype=="click"? "click" : "mouseenter", function(e){
                      delay(function() 
    { 
        if($(this).is(':hover')) {
   var menuinfo=jkmegamenu.megamenus[parseInt(this.getAttribute("_megamenupos"))]
   clearTimeout(menuinfo.hidetimer) //cancel hide menu timer
   return jkmegamenu.showmenu(e, parseInt(this.getAttribute("_megamenupos")))
        }}, 1000 );   
  })` and now the menu doesn't come up at all.